# Format USB external disk for Ubuntu using OSX diskutil

Tags: format

I want to format a USB external disk using OSX's `diskutil` command-line utility, and I want to use a format for this that plays well with Ubuntu.

The relevant format options I get from running `diskutil listFilesystems` are:

```
ExFAT
MS-DOS FAT
MS-DOS FAT12
MS-DOS FAT16
MS-DOS FAT32
Mac OS Extended
Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)
Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
```

If I had to guess, I'd pick `Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)`.  (I read somewhere that Linux systems don't like FSs with the "journaled" option, but I don't know if this [still] true.)

Is there a better choice as far as Ubuntu-compatibility is concerned?

Answer (score 1):

Through the Disk Utility UI (OS X 10) I just formatted a 32gb USB to Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Case sensitive) and my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can read the files on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the MacOS filesystems work with Ubuntu, so I can't answer that one.
But your remark about journaling filesystems is not true. The default FS on most Linux distros is EXT3 or EXT4, and both are journaling FS'es. So you don't have to worry about journaling and I would advise to choose a FS that offers this feature.

Maybe it's better to use a Linux utility to format your disk to play nice with MacOS, since (AFAIK) the EXT FS works very will with Mac. If the Mac utility offers this option, I would go for that.